# How do you send an action from one controller/router to another from a view?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm in a view and I want to send actions to a different controller or router than the view I'm in. How do I do this?

```
App.FormView = Ember.View.extend ({

    actions: {
        clicked: function() {
            context = this.get("context");
                App.OtherViewController.send("clicked", context); //this doesn't work
            // this.get("controller").send("clicked", context); // this sends to the current controller
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If your `FormController` `needs` some `ThingController` you can get it inside the `FormView` by doing `this.get('controller.controllers.thing')`.  From inside `FormController` you'd use `this.get('controllers.thing')`.

```
App.FormController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
  needs : ['thing']
});

App.FormView = Ember.View.extend ({
    actions: {
        clicked: function() {
            context = this.get("context");
            // this sends to the ThingController
            this.get("controller.controllers.thing").send("clicked", context); 
        }
    }
});
```